# Flutter: How to fix "A RenderFlex overflowed by pixels " error?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am using `GridView` in my `Flutter` app to display images and their titles. Please check the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../common_ui/search_bar.dart';

class PurchaseProductsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return PurchaseProductsUI();
  }
}

class PurchaseProductsUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _PurchaseProductUIState();
  }
}

class _PurchaseProductUIState extends State<PurchaseProductsUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: SearchBar(),
        ),
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: GridView.builder(
                physics: ScrollPhysics(), // to disable GridView's scrolling
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 20,
                gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), child: _buildImageBoxes());
                })),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImageBoxes() {
    return 
   Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random"),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child:  Text("Text"),        )
      ],
    );

  }
}
```

I get the following error and UI when I run the above code

```
I/flutter ( 2743): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2743): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 2743): A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 2743): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 2743): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 2743): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 2743): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 2743): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 2743): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter ( 2743): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter ( 2743): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 2743): The specific RenderFlex in question is:
I/flutter ( 2743):   RenderFlex#4a1bb OVERFLOWING
I/flutter ( 2743):   creator: Column ← Padding ← Container ← RepaintBoundary-[<14>] ← IndexedSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 2743):   NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverGrid ←
I/flutter ( 2743):   MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← ShrinkWrappingViewport ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 2743):   parentData: offset=Offset(5.0, 5.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 2743):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=150.0, h=150.0)
I/flutter ( 2743):   size: Size(150.0, 150.0)
I/flutter ( 2743):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 2743):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 2743):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 2743):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 2743):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 2743): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter ( 2743): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 2743): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 111 pixels on the bottom.
Reloaded 0 of 446 libraries in 1,179ms.
```

Below is the UI

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

try to use Expanded instead of Container in _buildImageBoxes() function

```
  Widget _buildImageBoxes() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/500/500/?random"),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text("Text"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

## `Expanded` → Calculated Space

`Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets in `Column` or `Row` will make Flutter calculate **remaining space** & use that space for layout.

Widgets not in `Expanded` or `Flexible` are laid out **regardless of screen/constraint space**.

---

## Why / How this works

`Column` and `Row` are laid out in two main phases:

1. non-`Flexible` items
2. `Flexible` items (`Expanded` and `Flexible` widgets)

#### Phase 1

Flutter does Phase 1 without screen size or any other constraint in mind.

Flutter just adds all non-flex-factor item sizes together.

Sum too big for screen or other constraint? → `RenderFlex overflowed` exception.

#### Phase 2

Widgets with `flex` constructor argument are flex-factor items.

i.e. `Flexible` or `Expanded` widgets. (`Spacer` too, but no one uses it.)

After Phase 1, any flex-factor widgets are laid out **with remaining space in mind**.

---

**Key difference** between non-flexible and flex-factor layout phases:

- non-flex layout → **regardless** of space
- flex-factor layout → uses **remaining** space

---

Inside `Column` or `Row`, wrapping widgets in `Expanded` or `Flexible`, Flutter will calculate remaining space for their layout.  This would prevent a `RenderFlex overflowed` exception in the question since each `Image` widget will **size itself to space constraints**.

But during Phase 1, **there are no space constraints**. So the `Images` aren't resized (and overflow).

Children widgets inside `Column` or `Row` *not* wrapped in `Expanded` or `Flexible` will be laid out at their intrinsic size, regardless of screen/constraint space.

#### Before

```
Space 400
  Column
    Image 150
    Image 150
    Image 150
```

Sum non-flex Images: 450. Space available: 400 → `Overflowed`

***Solution***: use Phase 2 → use calculated space

#### After

Wrapping `Image` in flex widget `Expanded`, height available is **calculated** then **shared** among `Expanded` (as constraints) and `Image` is resized to fit inside `Expanded` constraints:

```
Space 400
  Column
    Expanded 133
      → Image ←
    Expanded 133
      → Image ←
    Expanded 133
      → Image ←
```

Sum flex Expandeds: 399. Space: 400 → `OK`

Answer (score 5):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      height: _screenSize.height * 0.2,);
}
```

`MediaQuery.of(context)` It worked for me to use!

Answer (score 2):

#### Error (because of keyboard):

You can also run into this error while using a `TextField` which launches on-screen keyboard, to solve it set

```dart
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // <-- Set it to false.
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 600),
        TextField(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

#### Error (without keyboard):

Use `Expanded/Flexible` for your children in Column/Row.

- Using `Expanded`:

  ```dart
  Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Widget1(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Widget2(),
      )
    ],
  )
  ```
- Using `Flexible`:

  ```dart
  Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: Widget1(),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 2,
        child: Widget2(),
      )
    ],
  )
  ```
- Giving a fixed height:

  ```dart
  Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        child: Widget1(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Widget2(),
      )
    ],
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fit` property in your `Image.network` method to reduce the size of your image, since they are bigger and overflowing from your container, or you can enlarge your `Containers` by their `height` and `width` properties.

Comment: Used BoxFit.fill, BoxFit.cover, nothing changed.

Comment: @PeakGen wrap your image.network into a Expanded an everything will be fine

Comment: Could I please see some sample code of this fit property approach - where is that set ??