# How to fit row items to the screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Row:

```
    final Size _mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    File _storedImage;

     return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: _mediaQuery.width * 0.45,
          height: _mediaQuery.height * 0.35,
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
          child: _storedImage != null
              ? Image.file(_storedImage, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity)
              : Text('No image picked',),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
            label: Text('Take picture'),
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

The row is looking like this on an android device:

[image]

---

### A problem:

If I will give my container a larger width like `width: _mediaQuery.width * 0.65` the row items will no longer fit the row, and the right widget one will overflow from screen boundaries:

[image]

I will get this error:

`A RenderFlex overflowed by 31 pixels on the right. The relevant error-causing widget was:  _FlatButtonWithIcon`

---

**What I have done so far:**

Reading [flutter-how-to-fix-a-renderflex-overflowed-by-pixels-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261399/flutter-how-to-fix-a-renderflex-overflowed-by-pixels-error)

Checking the documentation for expanded - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

---

What do I need to change in my row so the 'Take a picture' button will fit inside the Row no matter what is the size of my container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct and it seems that the `Expanded` does not affect specifically the `icon` widget.

So find image that you want to show and use it instead of the `FlatButton.icon`

```
Expanded(child: Image.network('https://i.picsum.photos/id/9/250/250.jpg?hmac=tqDH5wEWHDN76mBIWEPzg1in6egMl49qZeguSaH9_VI%27'))
```

[image]

[image]

So the `Row` code will look like this

```
Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
          child: _storedImage != null
              ? Image.file(_storedImage, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity)
              : Text('No image picked',),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
        Expanded(child: Image.network('https://i.picsum.photos/id/9/250/250.jpg?hmac=tqDH5wEWHDN76mBIWEPzg1in6egMl49qZeguSaH9_VI%27'))
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the other `Container` with `Expanded` widget, then the layout will be divided equally for both of the widgets under the `Row` widget. If you want to one of these widgets take more space than the other you can experiment with the `flex` property of `Expanded` widget.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(flex: 2,
     child:Container(
      
      height: _mediaQuery.height * 0.35,
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
      child: _storedImage != null
          ? Image.file(_storedImage, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity)
          : Text('No image picked',),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    )),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: FlatButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
        label: Text('Take picture'),
        textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I want to be able to change my Container width and give the FlatButton.icon the remaining space of the screen, can you add an example of how It can be done?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I've updated the answer, you can use `flex` property of `Expanded` widget.

Comment: This actually looks the same, and the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

create a new file `size_config.dart` and paste the below code

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static double _screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double _blockWidth = 0;
  static double _blockHeight = 0;

  static double textMultiplier;
  static double imageSizeMultiplier;
  static double heightMultiplier;
  static double widthMultiplier;
  static bool isPortrait = true;
  static bool isMobilePortrait = false;

  void init(BoxConstraints constraints, Orientation orientation) {
    if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      _screenWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
      screenHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
      isPortrait = true;
      if (_screenWidth < 450) {
        isMobilePortrait = true;
      }
    } else {
      _screenWidth = constraints.maxHeight;
      screenHeight = constraints.maxWidth;
      isPortrait = false;
      isMobilePortrait = false;
    }

    _blockWidth = _screenWidth / 100;
    _blockHeight = screenHeight / 100;

    textMultiplier = _blockHeight;

    heightMultiplier = _blockHeight;

    if (screenHeight > 620) {
      textMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.15;

      heightMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.15;
    }
    if (screenHeight > 720) {
      textMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.25;

      heightMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.25;
    }
    if (screenHeight > 820) {
      print('called text multipler text multi value');
      textMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.25;

      heightMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.25;
    }
    if (screenHeight > 920) {
      textMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.30;
      heightMultiplier = _blockHeight / 1.30;
    }

    print('text multi value $textMultiplier $screenHeight $_blockHeight');
    imageSizeMultiplier = _blockWidth;

    widthMultiplier = _blockWidth;

    print(_screenWidth);
  }
}
```

now use `SizeConfig._screenWidth / 2` instead of _mediaquery
your image will cover the half of width according to the screen size and its a safe option (change the value according to your need)

(You can also use other variable of SizeConfig such as imageSizeMultiplier for image example `imageSizeMultiplier  * 20`,textMultiplier  for font Size)

Comment: Why Would I use `SizeConfig._screenWidth / 2` and basically this entire class instead of _mediaquery? Could you please elaborate and tell me how is your answer different than using _mediaquery?

Comment: The variable contain in SizeConfig is used to create a responsive design, its provide a different variables for different option, in your case using  SizeConfig._screenWidth / 2  will help you two divide widget into equal space.

Comment: I can also use this with _mediaquery tho

Comment: The problem solved for you by using /2??? or still...

Comment: Check guy luz answer, seems like icons can not work with Flexible